# SQLAlchemy session.merge() with condition

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I was wondering if it is possible to create some sort of session.merge(current_values) using a condition.
SQLAlchemy replaces the existing record (according to the specified 
kwargs As keys) but does it blindly (Not that it's bad, it's just I have a separate usecase).

Is it possible to do a session.merge() only if a given condition that involves the current existing value in the database is fulfilled?

```
if database_value>current_value:
    session.merge(current_value)
```